# Is there any markdown tools that support task lists

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have googled for a long time but can not find any tools that support `task lists` in `GFM`.

I tested this line in the tools:

```
- [x] This is a complete item
```

StackEdit, misaka, marked and so on, NONE of them worked while most of them claim `support GFM`.

Is there any tools support `task lists`?

PS：I know we can add this feature to StackEdit by `Custom` but just preview not export.

Comment: The only editor that supports Task List is the Github's own editor. One sad thing about it is that you cannot convert the .md file into another format such as .html or .pdf

Comment: @Adi, Oh no... Why those editors do not support for task list? license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution.

Using Python-MarkDown's Extensions can do a lot of things.

here is the link

[Python-Markdown](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/index.html)

[Third Party Extensions](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Third-Party-Extensions)

PS: A sublime text plug-in based on the project is recommeded

Answer (score 0):

Here's some more info on the solution the OP refers to:

https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/324#issuecomment-82646808

To enable it, follow these steps:

1. StackEdit > Settings > Extensions
2. Expand the **UserCustom** extension (bottom of the list)
3. Paste this code in the JavaScript code field:

   ```
   userCustom.onPreviewFinished = function() {
       $('#preview-contents dd').each(function() {
           $(this).html(function(index,html){
               return html.replace(/\[ ?\]/g,'<i class="icon-check-empty"></i>');
           });
           $(this).html(function(index,html){
               return html.replace(/\[X\]/ig,'<i class="icon-check"></i>');
           });
       });
       $('#preview-contents li').each(function() {
           $(this).html(function(index,html){
               return html.replace(/\[ ?\]/g,'<i class="icon-check-empty"></i>');
           });
           $(this).html(function(index,html){
               return html.replace(/\[X\]/ig,'<i class="icon-check"></i>');
           });
       }); 
   };
   ```

   4. Click **OK** to save the changes

Answer (score 0):

Version 5 of StackEdit that runs in the chrome app, and chrome extension support checklists.

The chrome app launches from https://stackedit.io/app#